# find $A ^\perp$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthogonality

for every  $u,w \in \mathbb{R^4}$ define inner product :$\langle u,w\rangle =\sum_{k=1}^{4} u_k w_k$ and $A= \{x \in \mathbb{R^4} | x=(a,a,b,b),a,b \in \mathbb{R}  \}$ now find $A ^\perp$.for non zero a,b we have : $ (\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{a},\frac{1}{b},\frac{-3}{b} ) 
 \in A^\perp$ and $A \oplus A^\perp = \mathbb{R^4}$

Comment: So, where are you running into difficulty in your efforts to solve this?

Comment: No, for $v$ to be in $A^{\perp}$, it must be orthogonal to **all** elements of $A$, no matter what $a$ and $b$ are.

Answer (score 1):

We have for $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \in \mathbb R^4$:

$x \in A^{\perp} \iff \langle x,(a,a,b,b)\rangle=0$  for all $a,b \iff a(x_1+x_2)+b(x_3+x_4)=0$ for all $a,b$.

Then it is easy to see that

$x \in A^{\perp} \iff x_2=-x_1$ and $x_4=-x_3 \iff x \in span\{(1,-1,0,0), (0,0,1,-1)\}$ .